# Selecting distinct - get one post per syndication_source

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to display **one post per** syndication source (stored in wp_postmeta).
vard_dump on $the_authors shows every source just once as it should.
After adding args to array I can get only one source with the same post multiple times.

Code:

```
function distinct_user(){
    global $wpdb;
    $the_authors = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key ='syndication_source'");
    //echo '<pre>';
    return($the_authors);
    //echo '</pre>';
}

$blogusers = distinct_user();
if ($blogusers) {
  foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
    $args = array(
      'author' => $bloguser->meta_value,
      'showposts' => 1
    );
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
//rest of the template
```

That args were working when I selected this:

```
$the_authors = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT DISTINCT post_author FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status='publish' AND post_type='post' AND post_author !='1' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 0,1000");
```

with

```
$args = array(
  'author' => $bloguser->post_author,
  'showposts' => 1
);
```

Can anyone point the problem?

Comment: It should print source a with it's post; source b with it's post; source c with it's post. But I can get only source a with it's post; source a with  it's post; source a with it's post; source a with it's post ...

Comment: SELECT is not the problem I think.

Comment: Tried also with: $the_authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id=wp_posts.ID WHERE post_status='publish' AND post_type='post' AND post_author !='1' AND meta_key ='syndication_source' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 0,1000"); but no luck